# check if current request is from mvc page in httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpmodule

Being new to MVC I have a question. In a http module, how can I find if the current request was from a mvc page ie http://www.website.com/user/edit

Is there something in the current context I can check for?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the controller and action name....

```
var request = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
string ActionName = request["Action"].ToString();
string ControllerName = request["Controller"].ToString();
```

Comment: Depending on where you want to use this code you may need to know the full namesapce which is: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Referrer property

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null 
    && Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.StartsWith( "/User/Edit/" ))
{
    return View( "SomeOtherView" );
}
```